# Porto's Socialfeed instagram - How to always get 4 images in 4 columns?

Tags: magento2, porto-theme, porto, instagram

Is there someone familiar with Porto's Socialfeed instagram module?
By default the module is always showing  6 images in 6 columns.

I only want to show 4 images, but when I select 4 it is showing 4 images in 6 columns. this doesn't look right. Does someone know how to achieve this? the module only contains a .phtml file

This is the source .phtml

```
  <?php
$_enable = $this->getConfig('sw_socialfeeds/instagram_photos/enable');
if($_enable==1){
    $accesstoken = $this->getConfig('sw_socialfeeds/instagram_photos/accesstocken');
    $count = $this->getConfig('sw_socialfeeds/instagram_photos/showing_counts') + 1;
    $padding = $this->getData("padding_item")!=''?'padding:'.$this->getData("padding_item").';':'';
    $template_type = $this->getData("template_type");
    $media_type = $this->getData("media_type");
    $album_name = $this->getData("album_name");
    $desktop = $this->getData("desktop") !='' ? $this->getData("desktop") : '4';
    $tablet = $this->getData("tablet") != '' ? $this->getData("tablet") : '4';
    $mobile = $this->getData("mobile") != '' ? $this->getData("mobile") : '2';
    $margin = $this->getData("margin") != '' ? $this->getData("margin") : '0';
    $desktop_large = $this->getData("desktop_large") != '' ? $this->getData("desktop_large") : $desktop;
?>
    <div class="insta-items grid-items">
      <?php if($template_type == 'carousel'):?>
        <div id="instafeed" class="photo-instagrams owl-carousel mb-0" style="opacity:0;"></div>
      <?php else: ?>
        <div id="instafeed" class="photo-instagrams row" style="margin-left: -<?php echo $this->getData("padding_item"); ?>;margin-right: -<?php echo $this->getData("padding_item");?>;opacity:0;"></div>
      <?php endif;?>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require([
            'jquery',
            'imagesloaded',
            'owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min'
        ], function ($) {
          var instagram = $('#instafeed'),
              token = '<?php echo $accesstoken;?>',
              count = '<?php echo $count;?>',
              <?php if($media_type == 'album'):?>
              media_type = 'CAROUSEL_ALBUM',
              <?php else: ?>
              media_type = 'IMAGE',
              <?php endif; ?>
              album_name = '<?php echo $album_name; ?>',
              url = '//graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=caption,id,media_type,media_url,children{media_url,permalink},permalink,thumbnail_url,timestamp,username&access_token=' + token,
              desktop_large = '<?php echo $desktop_large;?>',
              desktop = '<?php echo $desktop;?>',
              tablet = '<?php echo $tablet;?>',
              mobile = '<?php echo $mobile;?>',
              margin = <?php echo $margin;?>;
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            cache: false,
            url: url,
            success: function(data) {
              for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if (data.data[i]) {
                  if(data.data[i].media_type == media_type && media_type == 'IMAGE') {
                      <?php if($template_type == 'carousel'):?>
                        instagram.append("<div class='item insta-item' data-date='"+data.data[i].timestamp+"' data-sortid='"+i*2+"'><a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].permalink +"'><span class='content'><i class='porto-icon-instagram'></i></span><img class='instagram-image' src='" + data.data[i].media_url +"' /></a></div>");
                      <?php else: ?>
                        instagram.append("<div class='item insta-item item col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-sm4 col-6' style='<?php echo $padding;?>' data-date='"+data.data[i].timestamp+"' data-sortid='"+i*2+"'><a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].permalink +"'><span class='content'><i class='porto-icon-instagram'></i></span><img class='instagram-image' src='" + data.data[i].media_url +"' /></a></div>");
                      <?php endif;?>
                  }
                  if(data.data[i].media_type == media_type && media_type == 'CAROUSEL_ALBUM') {
                    if( data.data[i].caption != '' && data.data[i].caption == album_name){
                      for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                        if(data.data[i].children['data'][j]){
                          <?php if($template_type == 'carousel'):?>
                            instagram.append("<div class='item insta-item' data-date='"+data.data[i].timestamp+"' data-sortid='"+i*2+"'><a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].permalink +"'><span class='content'><i class='porto-icon-instagram'></i></span><img class='instagram-image' src='" + data.data[i].children['data'][j].media_url +"' /></a></div>");
                          <?php else: ?>
                            instagram.append("<div class='item insta-item item col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-sm4 col-6' style='<?php echo $padding;?>' data-date='"+data.data[i].timestamp+"' data-sortid='"+i*2+"'><a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].permalink +"'><span class='content'><i class='porto-icon-instagram'></i></span><img class='instagram-image' src='" + data.data[i].children['data'][j].media_url +"' /></a></div>");
                          <?php endif;?>
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              instagram.imagesLoaded().animate({ 'opacity' : 1 }, 500);
            <?php if($template_type == 'carousel'):?>
                instagram.imagesLoaded(function(){
                  instagram.owlCarousel({
                    loop: true,
                    margin: margin,
                    responsiveClass: true,
                    nav: false,
                    autoplay: false,
                    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                    dots: false,
                    lazyLoad: false,
                    responsive:{
                      0:{
                        items:mobile
                      },
                      600:{
                        items:tablet
                      },
                      1000:{
                        items:desktop
                      },
                      1400:{
                        items:desktop_large
                      }
                    }
                  });
                });
              <?php endif;?>
            }
          });
        });
    </script>
<?php }?>
```